# how do i make a active class which keep on my current page with a border effect

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am working with a project where i have amde a animation effect on every a tag which the user want to go an animation would appear and after that that page will get redirected. But the problem is that i want a border bottom on below of that current navbar.

`.index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="new__parent-navbar">
      <div class="new__logo">
        <a href="/getdata/startups" class="logo-link"
          ><h1 class=""><b>Header-issue</b></h1></a
        >
      </div>

      <div class="new__navbar h-nav">
        <ul class="new__nav-list v-class">
          <h4 class="">
            <li class=""><a href="/home.html">HOME</a></li>
          </h4>
          <h4 class="">
            <li class=""><a href="/about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
          </h4>
          <h4 class="">
            <li class=""><a href="/contact.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
          </h4>

          <h4 class="">
            <li class=""><a href="/job.html">JOBS</a></li>
          </h4>
          <!-- <h4 class="">
        <li class=""><a href="/login/startup" class="login-nav"> LOGIN</a></li>
      </h4> -->
        </ul>
        <h4 class="">
          <a class="login-nav" href="/login/startup">LOGIN</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <br />
      <br />
      <!-- <div class="rightNav v-class">
            <input type="text" name="search" id="search">
            <button class="btn btn-sm">SEARCH</button>
            <h1>rightnav</h1>
        </div> -->

      <div class="new__burger">
        <div class="new__line"></div>
        <div class="new__line"></div>
        <div class="new__line"></div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <script>
      burger = document.querySelector(".new__burger");
      navbar = document.querySelector(".new__navbar");
      // rightNav = document.querySelector('.rightNav')
      navlist = document.querySelector(".new__nav-list");
      black = document.querySelector(".b-black");

      burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
        navbar.classList.toggle("h-nav");
        //  rightNav.classList.toggle('v-class');
        navlist.classList.toggle("v-class");
        navbar.classList.toggle("b-black");
      });
      /* --------------------------------   Rachit Gupta */

      window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
        let header = document.querySelector("nav");
        header.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY > 0);
      });

      /* -------------------------------  End  */
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`style.css`

```
/* @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,400;1,100&family=Open+Sans&family=Raleway:wght@200;400&display=swap"); */

* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Raleway", serif;
  }
  
  body {
    font-family: "Raleway", serif;
    /* font-family:'Roboto Slab', serif; */
  }
  /* --------------------------------   Rachit Gupta */
   /* .new__parent-navbar {
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    transition: 0.6s;
    z-index: 5;
  } */
  
  nav.sticky {
    top: 0%;
    background: #FBFBFB;
    
    /* color:; */
    /* text-decoration: ; */
  }
  nav .sticky li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    /* background: rgb(27, 26, 90); */
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1.1rem; 
  } 
  
  /* -------------------------------  End  */
  .new__parent-navbar {
    display: flex;
    /*START of added code*/
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    z-index: 999;
    /*DONE*/
    /* background: white; */
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 1px rgb(152, 152, 152);
    /* border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px; */
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    padding: 7px 0px;
    /* width: 80%; */
  }
  /*Added*/
  a.active{
    text-decoration: 1px solid goldenrod;
    color: aquamarine;
  }
  .new__logo {
    width: 30%;/*changes*/
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: 300;
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    /* background: white; */
    color: rgb(78, 78, 167);
    /* font-size: 60px; */
  
    /* background-color: blue; */
  }
  .new__navbar {
    display: flex;
    /* background: white; */
    /* /* display: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left:0px; */
    /* z-index: 3;  */
  }
  .new__nav-list {
    width: 100%;
    /* background: #15114b; */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
  }



  .new__nav-list li {
    list-style: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px 10px;
  }
  .new__nav-list li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(21, 41, 123);
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1rem; /**/
  }
  .new__nav-list li a:hover {
    color: #2A528A;
  }
  
  .new__nav-list li a::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background: #fcd600;
    transition: width 0.3s;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  }
  
  .new__nav-list li a:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #search {
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 17px;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    border-radius: 9px;
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  .new__burger {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    right: 4%;
    top: 15px;
    display: none;
  }
  .new__line {
    width: 33px;
    /* background: #fff; */
    height: 4px;
    margin: 4px 3px;
    border-radius: 43px;
  }
  
  .logo-link {
    margin-left: 6%;
    color: rgb(23, 27, 135);
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 80px; /*made a change : 80px, No change*/ 
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px grey; /* added */
  }
  .logo-link:hover {
    color: navy; /*midnightblue;*/
    text-decoration: none;
    transform: scale(1.05);
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px grey;
  }
  /* .logo-link:focus {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  } */
  


  @media (max-width: 992px) {
    .new__parent-navbar {
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    .new__logo {
      padding-top: 10px;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .new__nav-list {
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .new__navbar {
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    .rightNav {
      text-align: center;
    }
    #search {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .new__burger {
      display: block;
    }
    .h-nav {
      height: 11px;
      /* height: 372px; */
    }
    .v-class {
      opacity: 0;
      display: none;
    }
  }
  /*My code  yogita*/
  .login-nav{
    height: auto;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 280px;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    background-color: navy;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #eee;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid navy;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 1px grey;
  }
  .login-nav:hover{
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px 1px grey;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 2px 3px grey;
    /* transform: scale(1.05); */
  }
  /* ---------------------end --------- */
```

`contact.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="new__parent-navbar">
      <div class="new__logo">
        <a href="""" class="logo-link"
          ><h1 class=""><b>Header-issue</b></h1></a
        >
      </div>

      <div class="new__navbar h-nav">
        <ul class="new__nav-list v-class">
          <h4 class="">
            <li class=""><a href="/home.html">HOME</a></li>
          </h4>
          <h4 class="">
            <li class=""><a href="/about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
          </h4>
          <h4 class="">
            <li class=""><a href="/contact.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
          </h4>

          <h4 class="">
            <li class=""><a href="/job.html">JOBS</a></li>
          </h4>
        </ul>
        <h4 class="">
          <a class="login-nav" href="/login/startup">LOGIN</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <br />
      <br />

      <div class="new__burger">
        <div class="new__line"></div>
        <div class="new__line"></div>
        <div class="new__line"></div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <script>
      burger = document.querySelector(".new__burger");
      navbar = document.querySelector(".new__navbar");
      // rightNav = document.querySelector('.rightNav')
      navlist = document.querySelector(".new__nav-list");
      black = document.querySelector(".b-black");

      burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
        navbar.classList.toggle("h-nav");
        //  rightNav.classList.toggle('v-class');
        navlist.classList.toggle("v-class");
        navbar.classList.toggle("b-black");
      });

      window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
        let header = document.querySelector("nav");
        header.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY > 0);
      });

      /* -------------------------------  End  */
    </script>
    contact
  </body>
</html>
```

and so on

and all the rest about, contact and job are same

Comment: Do your want css solution or you want js to add active class to current nav item dynamically?

Comment: anything which make this logic can happen i tried by putting active class in one and then .active and not active but in vain

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to get rid of the `/` before your page name ?

Change `<li class=""><a href="/contact.html">CONTACT US</a></li>`

By `<li class=""><a href="contact.html">CONTACT US</a></li>`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your HTML code is not semantic.
Your `active` class in current page with corresponding `<li>` or `<a>` with perfectly work fine.

Just need to unwrap `<li>`s from `<h4>`s.

In other words, write

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

in this structure and give bold/size styling via css.